# Passing SQLCommand Variable for Database Reference to MSBuild

Tags: visual-studio-2013, deployment, msbuild, database-project

I recently added a second database project to an existing solution which had working build definitions. I added a database reference to to the existing database project as there are a few Stored Procedures that reference both databases and this seems to be working fine and the solution builds.

However I am unable to deploy and keep getting the error 'Database2.publish.sql: Missing values for the following SqlCmd variables:Database1'

Under the build definition my MSBuild Arguments are:

```
    /t:Build /t:Publish /p:SqlPublishProfilePath=DEV.publish.xml
```

This was configured by a TFS consultant I no longer have access to so I am trying to figure out if the SQLCMD variable needs to be passed in the MSBuild Argument for the build or in the publish.xml and what the syntax would need to be in either case. I am using Visual Studio 2013 deploying to SQL 2014 databases.

**Update**: If I right click the project and publish manually, everything works fine, so issue seems to be figuring out how to pass database reference variable into the build definition

Comment: I'd set it up in the publish profile. You should be able to set the variable values there.  Any chance there's a DB reference you're using?

Comment: @PeterSchott Yes I am using a DB reference to another DB project in the same solution. I can pass this fine when I publish manually,  it's really the automated build where I cannot figure out where to set the variable.

Comment: Are you calling the publish profile through your automated build/deploy? We used SQLPackage.exe to do the actual push to the DB and that populated the variables for us automatically from the Publish Profile.  What do you get if you use the action to generate a script?